# C/C++ getch() function is not working as it should

Tags: c++, c++20, getch

When attempting to use the **getch() function** in order to read a keyboard input in my code, it just ends up reading all inputs until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. I'm trying to make my own **input** where it replaces each input with an asterisk.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int get_pass() {
    int pwd[9];

    cout << "Enter Your Password: ";

    for(signed int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        int pass_input;

        pass_input = getch();

        if (pass_input == 13) { // If the Enter key is pressed
            return 0;
        }

        pwd[i] = pass_input;

        cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    get_pass();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter Your Password: abc123
****** <- After I press Enter
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `getch` is a Microsoft-specific function. It's working the way I, and you apparently, expect on my computer. Are you running this program in an IDE where the terminal might not be respecting the Microsoft rules?

Comment: std::cout may buffer output. Investigate what that means & how it explains what you are seeing.

Comment: `get_pass` promises to return an `int`, but doesn't all of the time. Lying to the compiler can cause some pretty gnarly problems.

Comment: works ok for me - once i change getch to _getch ins vs2022

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're going to find it's the terminal displaying and buffering the input until enter is pressed and then passing it all to your program where it is handled correctly.

Comment: This is not a c++ problem this is a process problem.